# How to label the coordinates of the plotted graph?

Tags: plotting, graphics

How can I label the coordinates of the plotted graph? I want to label the coordinate of $(-1,-1)$.

```
Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Dashing[0.0155], Thickness[0.006]}, 
 Ticks -> {{-2 Pi, -Pi, 0, Pi}, {1, 2}}, Filling -> Axis, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.017], Point[{-1, -1.68}]}, 
 FillingStyle -> Yellow, Background -> LightGray]
```

Comment: Read the documentation for `Plot`.

Comment: I tried it and i got stucked.. I tried displayform but it brought me nowhere :( help me please

Comment: Please do not use the `graphs-and-networks` tag for plotting questions.  That tag is for [networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)), as made clear by its name.

Comment: Ok noted. im sorry. i just joined this awesome page :)

Comment: If your plot is not for a static use, e.g., in a print publication, then would it be sufficient to use a tooltip? Thus (with stripped down code for simplicity):`Plot[Tooltip[{2 Sin[x], 2 Cos[x]}], {x, -2 Pi, Pi}]`

Answer (score 6):

You were almost there.

```
 Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Dashing[0.0155], Thickness[0.006]}, 
  Ticks -> {{-2 Pi, -Pi, 0, Pi}, {1, 2}}, Filling -> Axis, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["label", Red, 14], {-1, -1}, {-1, 0}], PointSize[0.017], 
  Point[{-1, -1.68}]}, FillingStyle -> Yellow, Background -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To label more points (you can change to make your own labels as needed)

```
pts = {{-1, -1}, {-2, -1.5}};
Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Dashing[0.0155], 
   Thickness[0.006]}, Ticks -> {{-2 Pi, -Pi, 0, Pi}, {1, 2}}, 
   Filling -> Axis, Epilog -> {Text[Style[ToString[#], Red, 14], #, {-1, 0}] & /@ pts,
   PointSize[0.017], Point[{-1, -1.68}]},FillingStyle -> Yellow, 
   Background -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much. what should i do if i want to label two points?