# I want to create an arrow so that my output of my program will indicate 2 Sin x is the plotted graph

Tags: plotting

```
    Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, Pi}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Dashing[0.0155], Thickness[0.006]}, 
       Ticks -> {{-2 Pi, -Pi, 0, Pi}, {1, 2}}, Filling -> Axis, 
       Epilog -> {Text[Style["2 Sin(x)", Black, 10], {-1, -1}, {3.5, -26}], 
                  Text[Style["(-1,-1.68)", Black, 10], {-1, -1}, {-1.3, 6}], 
                   PointSize[0.017], Point[{-1, -1.68}]}, 
       FillingStyle -> Yellow, 
       Background -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: why did you delete your question here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44062/how-to-label-the-coordinate-of-the-plotted-graph-i-want-to-label-the-coordinate  right after I answered it?

Comment: @Nasser That's not cool, user3395043.  Nasser put in a lot of work, for free, to help you out.  His receiving upvotes and your accepting the best answer are the only forms of compensation the SE model offers.  Please respect that.

Comment: @Nasser and 
Michael. I am so sorry. i am new here. I think im accidentally deleted the post. How to do upvote? i tried it but i cant because i dont have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Drawing Tools "Palette":

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks but is there any code that we can use to create an arrow? i think if we can utilize "arrow" in documentation center, we might be able to sketch the arrow..

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach. It can be made more general,e.g, optional arguments to vary plot styling etc.

```
fun[f_, p0_, p1_, off_] := 
 Plot[f, {x, -2 Pi, Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Dashing[0.0155], Thickness[0.006]}, 
  Ticks -> {{-2 Pi, -Pi, 0, Pi}, {1, 2}}, Filling -> Axis, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style[f, Black, 10], p0 - off (p1 - p0)], 
    Arrow[{p0, p1}]}, FillingStyle -> Yellow, Background -> LightGray]
```

Now you can 'play' to chose position and arguments to achieve desired result:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{Image[fun[g, p, {q, g /. x -> q}, o], ImageSize -> 400], p}],
 {{g, 2 Sin[x], "functions"}, {2 Sin[x], 
   Cos[x]}}, {{p, {-1, 1}}, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}}, {q, -2, 2, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{o, 0.1, "offset"}, 0.1, 0.4, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it looks great but how do i insert the arrow command into my program? Please help me :(

Comment: @user3395043 you can use `Arrow` just as you would use `Line` (I suggest looking at the documentation of both). `fun` in my answer takes the arguments: function you wish to plot, the point of tail of the arrow (p0), where you want the head of the arrow (p1) and the offset of the text.  You could just copy and paste the contents of the function and supply your own arguments and play around.

Comment: I tried to add the Arrow command but it still cant produce the result.. this is my modified code..



Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Dashing[0.0155], Thickness[0.006]}, 
 Ticks -> {{-2 Pi, -Pi, 0, Pi}, {1, 2}}, Filling -> Axis, 
 Epilog -> {Text[Style["2 Sin(x)", Black, 10], {-1, -1}, {3.5, -26}], 
   Text[Style["(-1,-1.68)", Black, 10], {-1, -1}, {-1.3, 6}], 
   Arrow[{1, 2}, {2, 3}], PointSize[0.017], Point[{-1, -1.68}]}, 
 FillingStyle -> Yellow, Background -> LightGray]

Comment: @user3395043 I have altered your code. Your syntax for `Arrow` was incorrect. Needs to be `Arrow{{{x0,yo},{x1,y1}}]` Note extra {}. I have changed the coordinates of your text.Please look at code: `Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Dashing[0.0155], Thickness[0.006]}, 
 Ticks -> {{-2 Pi, -Pi, 0, Pi}, {1, 2}}, Filling -> Axis, 
 Epilog -> {Text[Style["2 Sin(x)", Black, 10], {-1.2, 1.2}], 
   Text[Style["(-1,-1.68)", Black, 10], {-1, -1}, {-1.3, 6}], 
   Arrow[{{-1, 1}, {0.2, 2 Sin[0.2]}}], PointSize[0.017], 
   Point[{-1, -1.68}]}, FillingStyle -> Yellow, 
 Background -> LightGray]`

Comment: Thank you so much!! Really Appreciate it!